# How to apply unit test on DAOs in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, dao

I don't know how to apply unit tests on data access layer. I always wonder if the data access layer should be tested. In my company, we have stable database to store unit test data and test data access layer by running data access objects and check the data they get from the stable database.

In order to pass the unit tests, data in the stable database can not be modified anymore. I think there is a better solution to this. If I am not mistaken, the the mock object cannot perform tests on SQL statements and `ResultSet` mappings.

What is the best way to unit test the DAO? Is there a better way to do this with TDD?

Comment: you can try DBUnit. It allows you to create datasets so that your test cases can operate on those datasets. before executing your tests, you can initialise the test data from the datasets into your database. this will allow you to have repeatable test results and "stable" database.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, by most definitions, "unit" tests do not depend on external systems like a database.   You want to create what are called "functional" or "integration" tests. In practice these types of tests will be implemented in the same way as unit tests, using something like Junit, but you should separate them from unit tests, which should run very fast and not break when your database is down or the data has changed.

Second, try to keep most of your business logic out of DAOs and instead put it into a service POJO layer so that you can test biz logic without involving the database.

Next, the ideal way to set up testing for DAOs is to start with an empty database, and load it with test data (often using the DAOs themselves), and then run your DAO tests against a known, and writable, test dataset.  If you're fortunate enough to have a read-only database, the `stable database` approach you outline will work, but most systems are read/write to the database.

Finally, it is valuable to test DAOs.  Often the database queries are some of the most fragile parts of your system, and you don't want to wait until they are deployed to production to find out they are breaking.

Comment: Very good point.  In fact, a DAO that incorporates any form of business logic is **not** a DAO: it's a MESS :-)

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, you're writing a functional test.  To do this you're going to need a test database of one sort or another.  Let's talk about your options.

1. HSQL/in-memory DB.  Small and fast.  Trivial to setup and get rolling, and great performance on unit test sized data.  The downside is, unless you are deploying using these environments then you risk having your unit test work but actual code fail.  It also means you can't use any SQL constructs which are not support in both HSQL and your production DB.  This can be mitigated to an extent by using Hibernate or similar.  A good way to go if you only have very simple queries.
2. Mock out the DB calls entirely.  Pointless unless you are doing too much heavy lifting in your DAO.
3. Use a test instance of your production DB.  This will give you the best results in terms of accuracy or results.  It will let you test to make sure that all your calls work as expected and lets you use non-portable SQL.  You can use something like DBUnit to load database data or just use the DAO under test to do it.  I would recommend this if you large and nasty queries.  Ones with a lot of edge cases, roll-up views and subtle behavior.  The downside is that real DBs will incur performance penalties since they'll be doing real work (transactions, index updates, rollback support).

Answer (score 2):

Some comments/suggestions:

1. The DAO test is aimed at verifying whether the queries fired and the data retrieved are as per the expectations. There should hardly any business logic to test in DAO.
2. Since the prime objective is test the database interaction, mocking is not going to make it foolproof, specially the edge cases.
3. In light of this, the approach that you have right now is fair enough. I am not sure why you feel that *its not good.* A little elaboration will help.
4. If you are not convenient on using external database, then you can use Java's inbuilt [javaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) for this. Please note that there will be overhead of creating the test data first before you run this test.

Comment: IMHO, it's not good because the OP is asking for **unit** testing.  His/her setup is not a unit testing one.

Comment: Well, then probably unit testing does not serve any purpose in DAO. The only automated test to test the code is what OP is already doing.

Comment: Not really.  To unit test business logic, she/he can use DBUnit, which was mentioned in another answer.  "Unit testing" against a real database is **not** unit testing.  Following the same logic, we could say that **unit testing in general** doesn't serve any purpose because any problem would be detected during functional or integration testing.

Comment: The main problem is one of terminology.  Many people calls "unit testing" to any form of automated testing, especially functional and integration.  This is not correct.  Unit, component, functional, and integration testing can all of them be manual or automated.

Answer (score 0):

For JDBC based project, JDBC connection can be mocked, so that tests can be executed without live RDBMS, with each test case isolated (no data conflict).

It allow to verify, persistence code passes proper queries/parameters (e.g. https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/anorm/src/test/scala/anorm/ParameterSpec.scala) and handle JDBC results (parsing/mapping) as expected.

Framework like jOOQ or my framework Acolyte can be used for: https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte .